# SQL Determine flag of a field

Tags: sql, database

I have a database that's used to keep a history of the registers that are open and closed

```
id | name | assigned_to | state | created_on | created_by
---------------------------------------------------------
1  | Jay  | 1           | OPEN  | 01/01/2011 | 1
2  | Kay  | 2           | OPEN  | 01/01/2011 | 1
3  | Jay  | 1           | CLOSED| 01/01/2111 | 1
```

"assigned_to" is the employee's id. 
"name" is the name of the register that they used.

What the database is saying is that "Jay" has been open and closed but "Kay" is not closed at all. I can't figure out a cleaver way to determine how to get only the register that is currently open. Any ideas on how to approach this? Keep in mind that there will be thousands of these as time progresses.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this?  Is `created_on` actually a `DATE` field, or character?

Comment: created_on is a date field. This is using a postgres database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a few assumptions, you can solve this as a "set-within-sets" subquery.  The major assumption is that a `name` is "closed" only once and is not opened again afterwards.  The following query checks that there is no `closed` state:

```
select r.name
from registers r
group by r.name
having sum(case when state = 'Closed' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

If a `name` can be opened after being closed, then you want to check the most recent time of each.  You can try this:

```
select r.name
from registers r
group by r.name
having sum(case when state = 'Closed' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 or
       max(case when state = 'Closed' then id end) > max(case when state = 'Opened' then id end);
```

Comment: I took the bottom one because there's a chance that the name could be reopened. I removed the sum section since all I have to do is check to make sure that a closed exists after an open. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `ROW_NUMBER()` to get the latest value per name, and list those with the latest state equal to `OPEN`;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY created_on DESC, id DESC) rn
  FROM myTable
)
SELECT id, name, assigned_to, state, created_on, created_by 
FROM cte WHERE rn=1 AND state='OPEN';
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e88ea/3).

Answer (score 0):

This will produce the rows with the latest created_on (by name) only if it has a state of "CLOSED".

```
select 
  *
from
  regs a
  join (select name,max(created_on) created_on
          from regs
         group by name)  b
        on a.name = b.name
where
  a.created_on = b.created_on
  and state = 'CLOSED'
```

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6d68f/5)